# KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/sharedStrings.xml' in the archive"

Tags: python, excel, pandas, glob, keyerror

Has anyone ever dealt with this key error? I am trying to read in an excel file with pandas.
I found this but it looks to be in Russian:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1077685/keyerror-there-is-no-item-named-xl-sharedstrings-xml-in-the-archive

The only way I could fix this is to manually open it then save it as a different name. Im trying to just download and go, with out having to do this 10+ times a day for a set of 5-6 files